# NuSOAP sending array of string

Tags: php, arrays, web, service, nusoap

The web service method I am trying to use can be seen here

http://documentation.rezexchange.com/cwi/cwidocumentation.html#Link9A

I am sending a NuSOAP request with these parameters

```
 $param = array(
    "PropertyCode" => get_option('re_propertycode'),
    "RateTypes" =>  array(
        "SSDB"
    ),
    "StartDate" => date('c', strtotime($rezStart)),
    "EndDate" => date('c', strtotime($rezEnd)),
    "Adults" => 1,
    "Children" => 0,
    "Infants" => 0
);
```

The request is ok except it is not recognising SSDB as I must be sending the array of strings in the wrong way.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: array("string" => "SSDB") fixed it but I still don't know how to have more than 1 value in the array

Answer (score 1):

Fixed with the following format

```
 $param = array(
    "PropertyCode" => get_option('re_propertycode'),
    "RateTypes" =>  array("string" => array("SSDB", "2NGT")),
    "EndDate" => date('c', strtotime($rezEnd)),
    "Adults" => $_POST['Adults'],
    "Children" => $_POST['Children'],
    "Infants" => $_POST['Infants']
);
```